# Spring securuty allow one GET request endpoint and authentication others

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a spring security config class where I'd want to allow a GET request endpoint `/api/check/status?appId=12345` in my spring boot MVC then have all others include authentication measures.

This is part of my config
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

```
http
    //Authenticate HTTP endpoints
   .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize            
        .requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher("/api/check/status?appId=**")).permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
    )
    //Sessions should be stateless
         .sessionManagement(smc -> smc
              .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS
    )
```

I with this, still asks for authentication. Can't figure how to get it allowed without auth. Anyone assist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the challenge, as below. Now works as expected.

```
.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
    .requestMatchers(antMatcher("/api/check/status")).permitAll()                    
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/check/status").permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
)
```

Try above configuration.
Idea is to define the request type and not to include the arguments in matcher

Answer (score 0):

As i know, you don't need write query-string in antMatcher(String pattern) method parameter.
because 'String pattern' need ant-style-pattern

there is method doc in antMatcher(String pattern) method

"
Creates a matcher with the specific pattern which will match all HTTP methods in a case-sensitive manner.

Params:
**pattern – the ant pattern to use for matching**
Since:
5.8"

so code is need to be like

```
.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize            
    .requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher("/api/check/status")).permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
)
```

for more detail about ant-style-pattern
look [this](https://bits.netbeans.org/11.2/javadoc/org-netbeans-modules-project-ant/index.html?org/netbeans/spi/project/support/ant/PathMatcher.html)